# how to build a custom player which looks like the official player

Tags: soundcloud

- I read the documentation about customizing players on developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player#
- I've downloaded the .js and .css from github (by the way, the " http://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/archives/master" link is not working).

But i would like to keep the "official - orange" skin of the player, and none of the custome player available looks similar.

I tried to start from an online player and deleted content via css to reach this very simple result: http://www.imerege.com/FTPdivers/SC.png

I did succeed to reach this result by changing "online" the css with Firefox Firebug, so i know it could works if I had the right files... But i don't know how to do it with the files provided on Github, as they are very different in their design and color.

Where could i find the right files / the basic player?

Thx for your help. 
Jérémie.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to go with something like http://waveformjs.org/ in order to draw the waveform and [SoundCloud JS SDK](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript) for getting SoundCloud sounds and playing them.

There is an example of how to use the two together on waveformjs website.

Comment: thx.
I can't find the example... Just see a broken link in the middle of the page...